# Erro ao criar a base de dados no postgres usando Ruby On Rails no windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gem

Ao rodar o comando no terminal para criar a base de dados do projecto em Rails no Postgres:

```
$ rails db:create
```

Aparece esse bug que não consigo resolver já faz tempo:

> ```
> rails aborted!
> LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.5/pg_ext
>
> Caused by:
> LoadError: cannot load such file -- pg_ext
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente você não instalou o módulo para postgresql, para instalar use:

```
gem install --pg
```

Comment: Guilherme, já se encontra instalado o módulo para postgres. instalei a gem pg requerido no projecto.. Mas mesmo assim o problema continua

Comment: @NdongalaGarcia Instalou o `rails` no cygwin?

Comment: Não Guilherme, não fiz a instalação do rails no cygwin ...  Então neste caso devo instalar o rails a partir do cygwin @Guilherme Nascimento ??

Comment: @NdongalaGarcia creio que sim, já que esta usando o RVM, não é mesmo?

Comment: Sim, já estou usando RVM @GuilhermeNascimento ...

Comment: então instala o `ruby` e o `gem` pelo RVM. Não me recordo se é assim o processo, já faz algum tempo que trabalhei com isto.

Comment: Está bem @Guilherme, farei as instalações e depois volto cá para dizer alguma coisa.. obrigado pelo apoio